# If vampire bites another vampire while in frenzy, do they risk blood bond?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

Blood bond chapter states the following (on page 100):

> Any time a character imbibes a point or more of Vitae, it
> creates or reinforces a blood bond.

Frenzy chapter states this (page 104):

> [While in frenzy] She can grab and bite as a single instant action,
> as she ravenously mauls her victim. Apply the successes on her
> Strength + Brawl roll to establish a grapple as lethal damage,
> and she takes an immediate point of Vitae from the victim.

Does this point of vitae run a risk of vitae addiction and blood bond?

Comment: How does 'while in frenzy' matter, please? What if one bit t'other without being in frenzy?

Comment: When vampire is in frenzy, they can grab and bite as one action. When they do so, they consume a point of vitae from victim.

Comment: Thanks and that explains what, please? Is there a difference between biting in frenzy, or otherwise?

It might be obvious that through biting with or without frenzy but are you using 'they' to mean only the biter, ungendered,?

Was I wrong to take 'they' to mean both biter and bitten?

Comment: Without special merits you don't get to grapple and bite as single action out of frenzy.

Comment: Thanks and how does that help? If you go back to your own citations of pages 100 and 104, how could they not combine to create or reinforce a blood bond?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes

Throughout the history of Vampire (both *the Masquerade* and then *the Requiem*) the insidious addictiveness of the Blood Bond has remained intact. It has always been a source of corruption and unnatural enslavement.

Vitae does not pick and choose, it attempts to bind the drinker into chains of unnatural emotional affection towards the owner of the blood. Frenzy or no frenzy matters not. Although, at most the drinker might feel the effects only after the Beast loosens its grip.

Kindred can still *attempt* to resist the bond as per the rules on page 100 in the Vampire: the Requiem Second Edition core rule book. But they are not immune.

Comment: Going into Frenzy is always bad for the character. Not for the story, though.